# Qt5 QML ListView contents zoom

Tags: image, qt, listview, scrollview, qml

I am trying to implement an image viewer (sort of):

- model/view approach
- using both c++ and qml
- the images are just a `ListView` filled up with `Image` (delegate) items

Here is a piece of code:

```
property double zoomFactor: 1.5;
property double imgScale: 1;

CustomToolBar
{
    id: toolBar
    onZoomInSignal:
    {
        imgScale = imgScale*zoomFactor;
    }
    onZoomOutSignal:
    {
        imgScale = imgScale/zoomFactor;

    }
    onZoomFitSignal:
    {
        imgScale = 1;
    }
}

Rectangle
{
    id: bgRect

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    color: "Grey"

    anchors.margins: 10

    ScrollView
    {
        id: scrollView
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView
        {
            id: listView

            anchors.fill: parent
            clip: true

            spacing: 10

            model: listItemModel

            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right

            anchors.margins: 10

            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

            delegate: Image
            {
                id: item_id

                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                source: item_img_path + "/" + Math.random()

                scale: imgScale
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The images are loaded correctly, I need to be able to zoom them.

In order to zoom I just modify the `scale` property of the `Image` delegate.

- Images not scaled (`scale = 1`) CORRECT:

[image: No zoom (scale = 1)]

- Images unzoomed (`scale = 1/1.5`) WRONG! images spacing (?) is being incremented:

[image: Zoom minus (scale = 1/1.5)]

- Images zoomed (`scale = 1.5`) WRONG! images overlap:

[image: Zoom plus (scale = 1.5)]

As you can see, *zoom minus* increments the spacing (I'm quite not sure it is really the spacing) between the images, and *zoom plus* overlaps the images.

Furthermore, it would be nice to have the horizontal scrollbar for the `ScrollView` when zooming in, but I cannot achieve this.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

Following the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023113/qt5-qml-listview-contents-zoom/31025902#31025902) proposed by [grillvott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5018578/grillvott) the images are zoomed in/out correctly, but the whole `ListView` is getting smaller/bigger with them:

[image]

The result should be instead something like this (gimp mode ON):

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Help me to understand you, how should the images look in the zoom in/out cases? Just as the same size than at scale 1?

Comment: well, they should be smaller/bigger as you can see in screenshots, but they shoud stay adherent one to each other as they are with scale = 1. Of course they MUST not overlap :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that `scale` will take any boundaries into consideration. You could encapsulate the image and use `fillMode` to make sure the image scales accordingly:

```
delegate: Item {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    width: img.sourceSize.width * imgScale
    height: img.sourceSize.height * imgScale
    Image {
        id: img
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: item_img_path + "/" + Math.random()
        fillMode: Image.Stretch
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thanks man..this works, the images are zoomed in/out correctly but the whole ListView is getting smaller/bigger with them :|

Comment: @Giancarlo What do you want then ? you said you don't want the images to overlap or the spacing to be bigger, you can't have that and be able to zoom unless you crop the image, and even then you'll get more spacing if images are made smaller.

Comment: well, I'd want the last screenshot to be real, if possible ;)

Comment: OK guys, problem solved. The solution worked as expected! I just had a scale property on the ListView @grillvott made my day.