# Qt5 QML scaling Image and Canvas

Tags: qt, canvas, qml

Here we are again, playing around with qml.

I am trying to draw on a `Canvas` which lives *over* an `Image`. I can draw correctly over the `Image` with this piece of code:

```
delegate: Item
{
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    width: img.sourceSize.width * imgScale
    height: img.sourceSize.height * imgScale

    Image
    {
        id: img
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: item_img_path + "/" + Math.random()
        fillMode: Image.Stretch
    }
    Canvas
    {
        id: markerCanvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        contextType: "2d"

        onPaint:
        {
            context.reset();
            context.globalAlpha = markerOpacity;

            if((true === drawingMarker) && (true === markerEnabled) && (-1 !== startXPos) && (-1 !== startYPos))
            {
                var l_obj = {"startXPos": startXPos, "startYPos": startYPos, "thickness": markerThickness, "color": markerColor};

                markerPoints.push(l_obj);
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < markerPoints.length; i++)
            {
                context.fillStyle = markerPoints[i]["color"];
                context.fillRect(markerPoints[i]["startXPos"], markerPoints[i]["startYPos"], markerPoints[i]["thickness"], markerPoints[i]["thickness"]);

             }
         }

         MouseArea
         {
             anchors.fill: parent
             onPressed:
             {
                 drawingMarker = true;
                 markerCanvas.forceActiveFocus()
                 startXPos = mouseX
                 startYPos = mouseY
                 markerCanvas.requestPaint()
             }
             onMouseXChanged:
             {
                 startXPos = mouseX
                 startYPos = mouseY
                 markerCanvas.requestPaint()
             }
             onMouseYChanged:
             {
                 startXPos = mouseX
                 startYPos = mouseY
                 markerCanvas.requestPaint()
             }
             onReleased:
             {
                 endXPos = mouseX;
                 endYPos = mouseY;
                 drawingMarker = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Trouble begins when I scale the image (zoom in/out):

[image]

Why is the `Canvas` getting *duplicated*, and why the draw coordinates are getting screwed up?

The result is the same even if I puth the `Canvas` object *inside* the `Image`.

I would like to have the `Canvas` scaled exactly like the `Image` does, avoiding to be duplicated, and keeping the drawing coordinates consistent with the new scale.

Any help?

Thank you all

Comment: Your `Canvas` and `Image` are used in a delegate - a delegate of _what_?  Instead of scaling the contents of the delegate, you are setting the size of the delegate, causing the `markerPoints` to not stay the same size relative to the `Image`.  If you put the `Canvas`, `Image`, and `MouseArea` into an `Item` (as a child of the current top-level `Item`) then used `imgScale` as its scaling factor, then I think a lot of your coordinate problems will vanish.

Comment: delegate of a c++ class, can't put all the source code here because too much... however putting another Item around didn't solved, rather, things got worse

Comment: "things got worse" You've got enough rep to know that doesn't help - show your code changes, _how_ did things get worse?

Comment: well, I am showing a list of images... putting another Item around the delegate is preventing the images from being loaded: I see that the qml is requesting ALL the images to the ImageProvider and no one is being shown, instead the correct behavior is one image requested and shown at time. When scrolling down the list, the nex images should be requested. See my previous question about this project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023113/qt5-qml-listview-contents-zoom